# Can not import 3rd party libs into sbt console

Tags: scala, sbt

Every time when I try to import 3rd part libs into `sbt console` as the following:

```
scala> import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
              ^
       error: not found: value eu
```

As you can, I have got the error message.

The `build.sbt` is defined as follows:

```
import Dependencies._

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization := "io.databaker"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "databaker"

lazy val tests = (project in file("modules/tests"))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(
    name := "user-svc-test-suite",
    /*   scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-deprecation",
      "-encoding", "UTF-8",
      "-language:higherKinds",
      "-language:postfixOps",
      "-feature",
      //"-Xfatal-warnings",
      "-Ymacro-annotations",
      "-language:implicitConversions"
    ),*/
    scalafmtOnCompile := true,
    Defaults.itSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          CompilerPlugins.better_monadic_for,
          CompilerPlugins.context_applied,
          CompilerPlugins.kind_projector,
          TestLibraries.weaver
        ),
    testFrameworks += new TestFramework("weaver.framework.TestFramework")
  )
  .dependsOn(core)

lazy val core = (project in file("modules/core"))
  .enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "user-svc-core",
    scalafmtOnCompile := true,
    mainClass := Some("io.example.Main"),
    containerPort := 9090,
    resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
    Defaults.itSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          CompilerPlugins.better_monadic_for,
          CompilerPlugins.context_applied,
          CompilerPlugins.kind_projector,
          Libraries.cats,
          Libraries.cats_meow_mtl,
          Libraries.cats_effect,
          Libraries.cats_meow_mtl_core,
          Libraries.cats_meow_mtl_effects,
          Libraries.circe_core,
          Libraries.circe_generic,
          Libraries.circe_parser,
          Libraries.circe_refined,
          Libraries.ciris_core,
          Libraries.ciris_enum,
          Libraries.ciris_refined,
          Libraries.http4s_dsl,
          Libraries.http4s_server,
          Libraries.http4s_servlet,
          Libraries.http4s_client,
          Libraries.http4s_circe,
          Libraries.refined_core,
          Libraries.refined_cats,
          Libraries.log4cats,
          Libraries.newtype,
          Libraries.servlet,
          Libraries.doobie_core,
          Libraries.doobie_postgres
        )
  )
```

Why it is not possible to import 3rd party libs into `sbt console`?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have to change to the sub-project `core` before executing `console`, that is, first execute

```
sbt
```

then change project

```
project core
```

then

```
console
```

The reason is refined is defined as `libraryDependency` of `core` project instead of root project. A one-liner would be

```
sbt "project core" console
```

Comment: Or just `sbt core/console`.